accessing VariantProps defined with Eva
I'm trying to access VariantProps defined with class-variance-authority, the props are connected using an interface to the button:
import React, {ComponentPropsWithRef } from "react";
import { type VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority";
import { buttonStyles } from "./variants";

type ButtonElementProps = ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>;


export interface ButtonProps
  extends Omit<ButtonElementProps, "color"> ,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonStyles> {
  leftIcon?: React.ReactNode;
  rightIcon?: React.ReactNode;
  label?: string;
  test?: string;
}

When I try to import the button in another project I can access to props like leftIcon, rightIcon and label but not the ones defined inside buttonStyles
